# Meaning of the idiom "keeping my head out of the oven"

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does the idiom "to keep one's head out of the oven" mean? I heard the phrase in this context:

> "Hey John, how's it goin'?"
>
> "Oh, you know... keeping my head out of the oven."

Comment: It's debatable whether "keep my head out of the oven" (and variants) are used commonly enough to qualify as a _fixed expression_ (of which idioms are a subset).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Back in the days when ovens were often powered by gas with no added chemicals to make it smell bad, a purported method of suicide was to stick your head in the oven and turn on the gas without lighting it (the modern equivalent would be running your car in a closed garage). While that was quite a while ago now, I can't think of any other meaning this phrase could have.

Exactly what this translates to in terms of how well John is doing depends on his personality. If John is the sort to joke about committing suicide, I would probably take the meaning as: things aren't as bad as they could be, but they're not very good, either. If John seems like the type of person who wouldn't joke about committing suicide, you might want to take this much more seriously.

Comment: +1 For getting the literal meaning right. However, what they are actually saying here is *not* that things themselves aren't horrible (as you imply), but rather that they are managing not to get so depressed about it that they commit suicide. Its more a statement of perseverence.

Comment: More gruesome than I expected!

Comment: Absolutely agree with @T.E.D. that such a reply should be interpreted as meaning *"Things are* **worse** *than you probably think"*. Most likely the other person had no idea things might be so bad that John would even have *thought* of suicide. Obviously in reality it's just light-hearted exaggeration, but [many a true word is spoken in jest](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/many-a-true-word.html), so I'd still tend to think that even if John isn't *really* thinking about ending it all, he's probably not feeling too good about his life right now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks. Everybody has very good points about the seriousness of suicide. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't know if it would even be understood in the US, but in my neck of the woods we haven't spoken of gas ovens or car exhausts for decades. We just say it's lucky you can never find a [Stanley Knife](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stanley+knife&hl=en&newwindow=1&biw=1427&bih=920&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=LI5nTvfeEszD8QO44-zNCw&ved=0CHgQsAQ) when you "need" one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I definitely remember putting one's "head in the oven" being used for suicide when I was a child, so it used to be understood in the U.S. as well. But this expression surely is slowly dying.

Comment: Having lost a few friends & relatives to suicide myself over the years, I'm well aware how serious things can get. But I firmly believe talking helps (it's mostly been "the quiet ones"), and I often think a flippant attitude in company is safer than deadly seriousness in isolation.

Comment: Sylvia Plath, an American poet, committed suicide by this method in 1963.

Comment: What is 'coal gas'? Is that the BrE term for the AmE 'natural gas'? Why was this changed by 'Community'?

Comment: @Mitch: [Coal gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal_gas) was apparently used in both the U.K. and the U.S. before it was replaced by natural gas. Wikipedia says it's considerably more poisonous.

Comment: I rolled back the edit, since this seemed odd to me. Feel free to undo it if you agree with the change @Peter.

Comment: @KitFox: I changed it to "gas". The exact type doesn't really matter for this answer.